# What's the standard practice for naming labels in Go?

Tags: go, coding-style, naming-conventions, control-flow, continue

[Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec) and [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#names) gives guidelines for naming packages, types, functions, and variables. There's also a [blog post](https://blog.golang.org/package-names) discussing about package names. But none of articles seem to talk about naming conventions of labels used with `goto`, `break` and `continue`.

I believe the best practice is to avoid labels altogether, but what's the standard convention for those control flow labels in Go?

Please note that this question is not asking for naming recommendations. I just thought it would be good to know what guidelines Google provide about it or how they actually use it.

Comment: As has been mentioned before: there is no official convention, guideline, or standard practice for label names. Any other answer will be subjective.

Comment: Yeah, the convention to write label names is just to use `MixedCaps` or `mixedCaps` rather than underscores.

Comment: @Coconut: So in other words, there is no convention for labels. There's just the existing convention for naming anything in Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code of the Go standard library and internal packages, they tend to name labels in the same manner variables are usually named.

So it's okay for labels to have any combination of either upper or lower-case characters, as long as you don't use underscores for writing anything.

See https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#mixed-caps

> #### MixedCaps
>
> Finally, the convention in Go is to use `MixedCaps` or `mixedCaps` rather than underscores to write multiword names.

Some examples:

https://golang.org/src/cmd/internal/obj/x86/pcrelative_test.go#L102

```
continue LOOP
```

https://golang.org/src/compress/lzw/reader.go#L198

```
break loop
```

https://golang.org/src/compress/flate/deflate.go#L402

```
break Loop
```

https://golang.org/src/debug/gosym/symtab.go#L429

```
break countloop
```

https://golang.org/src/encoding/csv/reader.go#L308

```
break parseField
```

https://golang.org/src/crypto/dsa/dsa.go#L128

```
break GeneratePrimes
```

https://golang.org/src/go/types/testdata/labels.src

```
func f3() {
L1:
L2:
L3:
    for {
        break L1 /* ERROR "invalid break label L1" */
        break L2 /* ERROR "invalid break label L2" */
        break L3
        continue L1 /* ERROR "invalid continue label L1" */
        continue L2 /* ERROR "invalid continue label L2" */
        continue L3
        goto L1
        goto L2
        goto L3
    }
}
```

---

All sample snippets from [Go language spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec) write all labels in `CamelCase`. And the word `Loop` is often abbreviated to `L` in both the spec and the implementation.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Break_statements

```
OuterLoop:
    for i = 0; i < n; i++ {
        for j = 0; j < m; j++ {
            switch a[i][j] {
            case nil:
                state = Error
                break OuterLoop
            case item:
                state = Found
                break OuterLoop
            }
        }
    }
```

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Continue_statements

```
RowLoop:
    for y, row := range rows {
        for x, data := range row {
            if data == endOfRow {
                continue RowLoop
            }
            row[x] = data + bias(x, y)
        }
    }
```

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Goto_statements

```
goto Error
```

```
    goto L  // BAD
    v := 3
L:
```

```
if n%2 == 1 {
    goto L1
}
for n > 0 {
    f()
    n--
L1:
    f()
    n--
}
```